# How to count all rows in a list with more than one criteria

Tags: excel

I want to count all the rows for specific values in a list

for example, if i want to count rows from this sheet for columns c, f and j
[image]

and seperate them by their values here:
[image]

what would be the best way to do this?

I tried using:

```
=COUNTIFS('REBOUND DEFECT LOG AND HOPPER'!C:C,'Area '!B4,'REBOUND DEFECT LOG AND HOPPER'!F:F,'Area '!C2,'REBOUND DEFECT LOG AND HOPPER'!J:J,'Area '!C3)
```

but it isn't giving the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel365, the new dynamic array function FILTER is just what you are looking for.
for instance, in your table you can use:

```
=Count(FILTER(C4:C12,sheet1!D4:D12="Recived",sheet!E4:E12="In Process"))
```

To count the rows where the values in sheet 1 that feet two criteria.
Sorry, I don't quite understand the logic you require in you question so this is a general answer/